# Dynmaic registration of BroadcastReceiver's actions (intent-filter)

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver and a Service in my application. I am receiving the action information in the service from an activity. I have to register this action dynamically with the receiver. I have a few actions defined in the AndroidManifest.xml, but this action has to be defined dynamically. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

P.S. A sample receiver tag from the AndroidManifest.xml. BOOT_COMPLETED is one of the actions I am referring to. I am receiving this information in this service.

```
<receiver android:name="com.test.TestReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
YourReceiver receiver = new YourReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager mBroadcastMgr = LocalBroadcastManager
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
mBroadcastMgr.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks, Misagh. Can I use registerReceiver( ) with LocalBroadcastManager if the receiver is already registered in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I'm not sure. But why you want to do that?

Comment: I am just trying to understand the details. In the example you mentioned, Is "YourReceiver" also present in the AndroidManifest.xml. Or, is it just another class which is defined, but not present in the manifest.xml

Comment: Thanks, Misagh for the help. :)